# two different elements' submit and click events handled by same jquery function?

Tags: events, event-handling, jquery

I have a submit button `#next_step` and a link `#design_next_step`.

When the button submitted or the link is clicked, the same function is triggered.

How can I do something like this?

`$('#next_step').submit(), $('#design_next_step').click(){function(){ ... });`

Comment: if your button(input) type is submit, you just need to handle click event

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just make both event handlers to call the same function F.

```
$('#next_step').submit(function() {
   F();
});
$('#design_next_step').click(function() {
   F();
});
var F=function() {
   . . .Write code here
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use the standard CSS comma to define a group selector:

```
$('#next_step, #design_next_step').on('submit click', function(){ ... });
```

> When the button submitted or the link is clicked...

But *buttons* aren't submitted, they're clicked. The `submit` event relates to `form` elements, not `button` or `input` elements. Assuming that the `id`s you've shown there are for elements that are buttons or links, just use the `click` event:

```
$('#next_step, #design_next_step').on('click', function(){ ... });
```

Depending on what you're doing, you may — or may not — want to prevent the default action for the event [by accepting the `event` argument and calling `preventDefault` on it, or by doing `return false` in the handler which will both prevent the default and stop propagation]. The default action for `click` on links is to follow the link, for instance.

Comment: Oh you're right...buttons aren't submitted. But what about if `#next_step` is `input type='submit'`. Isn't  `$('#next_step').submit()` valid code?

Comment: @user961627: It's valid code, but it won't do anything. :-) The `submit` event is fired on `form` elements. When you click a `submit` button, the event fired on the button is `click`.

Answer (score 2):

you can give same class to both, the link as well as the button and then you can try doing following

```
$('.className').click(function() {
    var item = $(this); // item that triggered the event

});
```

and if you want to do based in IDs then following

```
$('#Button1, #Link1').click(function() {
    // You can use `this` to refer to the source element, for instance:
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is no way to do like that

Instead try to use same function in event handlers

```
$('#formId').submit(function{
   execute();
});

 $('#design_next_step').click(function{
 execute();
 })
```

Comment: Stop trying to submit buttons!

Comment: @Jonathan Sorry,I didn't get you.

Comment: You need to submit the `form`, the button can't

Comment: @Jonathan Oops..thanks for the spot Jonathan.My intention is that write one function and use multiple times :)

Answer (score 0):

This would be more appropriate.

```
$('.anchor').click(function{
   $('form').submit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you can just call it like you would call a normal function.Since in this case submit and click perform the same action ,when the user submits or clicks the link,they call the funcion "myFunction"

```
                function myFunction()
                      {
                        ..........
                      }
                $('#button').submit(myFunction);
                $('#link').click(myFunction);
```

or

```
                 var myFunction=function()
                    {
                       .......
                    }

                  $('#button').submit(myFunction);
                  $('#link').click(myFunction);
```